# Is there a way to set a custom html steps with IntegerField?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I need to modify the fields generated by wtforms to be using step="0.125" instead of step="1"

Example:

```
age_max = IntegerField(
    "Age max",
    default=120,
    validators=[validators.NumberRange(min=0, max=120), validators.InputRequired()],
    id="age_max",
)
```

generates this html:

```
<input id="age_min" max="120" min="0" name="age_min" required="" step="1" type="number" value="0">
```

but I need to modify the step in the html to be another value like "0.125"

If I modify the library functions functions directly I can use whatever value I need but It's realy not how it shoud be done

here is where I can modify the source code to set the value:
env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wtforms_components/fields/html5.py

So what is the most optimal way of modifying the step attribute of an input generated by wtForm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just not looking at the right place, here is how to do it (with render_kw):

```
age_min = IntegerField(
    "Age min",
    validators=[validators.NumberRange(min=0, max=120), validators.InputRequired()],
    id="age_min",
    render_kw={"step": "0.125"},
)
```